# why the jQuery click event does not work multiple times in my multi-step form?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-blade

I use laravel blade and jquery , 
 I want to make a form with several steps , 
everything works except the next button, when i use it in the first fieldset it's okay, but in the second fieldset it does not work anymore i mean when i click a second time nothing happens, someone could check my code or give a hint ?

```
@section('content')
    <div class="page-content get-a-quote get-a-quote-2">
        <div class="container-fluid">

            <div class="row p-5 bg-whitesmoke">
            {!! Form::open(['route' => '','class'=> 'col-12']) !!}
            <!-- start -->
                <!-- step-1 -->
                <fieldset>
                    <h3 class="text-capitalize">profil</h3>
                    <div class="bg-white p-5">
                        <!-- full name -->
                        <div class="form-group row ">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Nom et prénom</label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                {{ Form::text('nom_et_prenoms', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!-- next boutton  -->
                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <button   type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="next_btn">Suivant</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <!-- step-2 -->
                <fieldset>
                    <h3 class="text-capitalize">Coordonnées</h3>
                    <div class="bg-white p-5">

                        <div class="form-group row ">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">email
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                {{ Form::email('email', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'required']) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>


                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="prev_btn">Précédent</button>
                                <button  type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="next_btn">Suivant</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>

                <!-- step-2 -->
                <fieldset>
                    <h3 class="text-capitalize">assurance</h3>
                    <div class="bg-white p-5">

                        <div class="form-group row ">
                            <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-4 col-form-label">Date de début
                            </label>
                            <div class="col-sm-8">
                                {{ Form::date('date_de_debut', \Carbon\Carbon::now(), ['class' => 'au-form-control au-form-radius', 'required', 'placeholder'=> 'jj-mm-aaaa']) }}
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <div class="col-sm-10">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="prev_btn">
                                    précédent
                                </button>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submit_btn">
                                    Lancer le simulateur
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
                <!-- end -->
                {!! Form::close() !!}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

my javascript(jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    var current_fs, next_fs, previous_fs; //fieldsets

    $("#next_btn").click(function() {
        current_fs = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        next_fs = $(this).parents('fieldset').next();
        //show the next fieldset
        next_fs.show();
        // hide the current fieldset
        current_fs.hide();
    });

    $("#prev_btn").click(function() {
        current_fs = $(this).parents('fieldset');
        previous_fs = $(this).parents('fieldset').prev();
        //show the previous fieldset
        previous_fs.show();
        //hide the current fieldset with style
        current_fs.hide();
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(not a laravel user here)*

You should avoid having multiple ids like `#next_btn`.

Try with a class `.next-btn` instead, it may fix the onclick to retrieve the step3 fieldset when clicking on next btn in second fieldset.

Note: also, replace nth use of `$(this).parents('fieldset')` by the variable you created `current_fs`.